# How do I get the height attribute from jCrop

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this directive that uses jQuery. I can't get `height` or `width` out of `myImage`

```
cmsApp.directive('imgCropped', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: { src:'@', selected:'&' },
    link: function(scope,element, attr) {
      var myImg;
      var clear = function() {
        if (myImg) {
          myImg.next().remove();
          myImg.remove();
          myImg = undefined;
        }
      };
      scope.$watch('src', function(nv) {        
        clear();
        if (nv) {
          element.after('<img />');
          myImg = element.next();  
          myImg.attr('src',nv);
          console.log(myImg[0]);
          console.log(myImg);

          $(myImg).Jcrop({
            trackDocument: true,  
            onSelect: function(x) {              
              scope.$apply(function() {
                scope.selected({cords: x});
              });
            },
            aspectRatio:1
          });
        }
      });

      scope.$on('$destroy', clear);
    }
  };
});
```

The `console.log(myImg)` returns this, minus all the event listeners and stuff

```
    [img, ready: function, toString: function, eq: function, push: function, sort: function…]
0: img
height: 259
naturalHeight: 259
naturalWidth: 417
width: 417
x: 0
y: 0
__proto__: HTMLImageElement
length: 1
```

The width and height are right there. I just can't get them.

`myImg[0].height` returns 0.

### EDIT: PLUNKER

Here's a "working" example that attempts to `console.log` various attributes of `myImg`

http://plnkr.co/edit/sGIdfi2b8UztEl2DEhf7?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to retrieve them by just:

```
myImg.naturalHeight
myImg.naturalWidth
```

### UPDATE

as per the plunker, the problem is you need to access the properties after you have load the image, so:

```
$(myImg).load(function(){
    console.log(myImg[0].naturalHeight);
});
```

is working! Forked here: http://plnkr.co/edit/DBey1vrD0QSgJhPc3ApX?p=preview

Comment: That returns `undefined` You can't see it, but in the chrome console it says that `myImg` is an array, and all the properties is in the first index of the array. `myImg[0].naturalHeight` returns 0.

Comment: Your updated worked. Do you happen to know why I can do `console.log(myImg[0])` and see the height and width, but I can only access it after loading it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jQuery **before** Angular. Then you can just do:

```
console.log(myImg.height());
console.log(myImg.width());
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZjciYt4I4VxT8wPQmCTa?p=preview

**But**, you have another problem here. You are querying for the height and width, **immediately** after you set the image **src** attribute. So, at less is a tiny image, the first time you query for the height and width, you'll get **0**, since the image hasn't been loaded yet. You can work around this, by this querying for the height and width **after** the image has been loaded (listening to the image **load** event).

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/hV2mNvT07qLZFLXHcUuo?p=preview

**EDIT**
Also, I didn't explain why you need to include jQuery **before** angular, sorry. Angular will use jQuery if it's included first, but if it doesn't find it, it will use **jqLite**. You can check more info on http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element, but basically, and quoting from the documentation:

> jqLite implements only the most commonly needed functionality with the goal of having a very small footprint

**height()** and **width()** are not included in jqLite.